# Displaying aChartengine using Listview Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, achartengine

I am trying to display aChartengine pie chart inside a listview using a custom adapter , it is executing without any error but not displaying chart ..please help.
I have a method openChart()..which is creating chart and returning view which I am setting in the get view through holder.
    code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

.....

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chart,null);
                holder.vw=(ViewGroup) convertView.findViewById(id.chart_container);
                //Log.w("In View", );
                holder.vw.addView(openChart());
convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

....
private View openChart(){


        // Pie Chart Section Names
        String[] code = new String[] {
            "Eclair & Older", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb",
            "IceCream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean"
        };

        // Pie Chart Section Value
        double[] distribution = { 3.9, 12.9, 55.8, 1.9, 23.7, 1.8 } ;

        // Color of each Pie Chart Sections
        int[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.RED,
                        Color.YELLOW };

        // Instantiating CategorySeries to plot Pie Chart
        CategorySeries distributionSeries = new CategorySeries("PIe");
        for(int i=0 ;i < distribution.length;i++){
            // Adding a slice with its values and name to the Pie Chart
            distributionSeries.add(code[i], distribution[i]);
        }

        // Instantiating a renderer for the Pie Chart
        DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer  = new DefaultRenderer();
        for(int i = 0 ;i<distribution.length;i++){
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
            // Adding a renderer for a slice
            defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        }

        defaultRenderer.setChartTitle("Android version distribution as on October 1, 2012 ");
        defaultRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        defaultRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
     // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
        //LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);


        // Creating a Line Chart
        mChart = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(mContext, distributionSeries , defaultRenderer);

        // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
        //chartContainer.addView(mChart);

        // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
       // Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(getBaseContext(), distributionSeries , defaultRenderer, "AChartEnginePieChartDemo");

        // Start Activity
       // startActivity(intent);
        Log.w("In Chart", mChart.toString() +"");
        return mChart;

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();` in your else statement if you are not using it? Also you are not updating you convertView if it is not null.

Comment: I have copy pasted it ..i will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the same issue a while ago. In my case I had to give the graph view a fixed height.
You can also give fixed height to one of the graph view's parents and then use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` on the graph view.

See my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/plot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_item_margin"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"/>

        <!-- other views... -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is probably done because ListView wants to minimize the height of its items. If this is true, your graph was there, but its height was zero.

Comment: I'm glad it works. :)
Would you mind marking my answer as correct? :)